# If $f^3_n\to f^3$ in $L^2(0,\pi)$ then $f_n\to f$ in $L^6(0,\pi)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

This question is brief, does this statement hold:

**If $f^3_n\to f^3$ in $L^2(0,\pi)$ then $f_n\to f$ in $L^6(0,\pi)$?**

and how about this

**If $g^3_n\to g^3$ in $L^2(0,\pi;L^2(0,\pi))$ then $g_n\to g$ in $L^2(0,\pi;L^6(0,\pi))$?**

Answer (score 2):

The operation $f \mapsto f^{1/3}$ maps $L^2$ into $L^6$, hence it is continuous:
After extracting subsequence, $f_n\to f$ pointwise a.e. We have the upper bounds
$$
|f_n-f|^6 \le 2^5(|f_n|^6+|f|^6).
$$
The right-hand side converges pointwise. Moreover its integral converges too:
$$
\int |f_n|^6 = \int |f_n^3|^2 \to \int |f|^6.
$$
Then by a variant of dominated convergence:
[Variant of dominated convergence theorem, does it follow that $\int f_n \to \int f$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1862764/variant-of-dominated-convergence-theorem-does-it-follow-that-int-f-n-to-int)
we get the convergence
$$
\int |f_n-f|^6 \to 0.
$$
Therefore, the first claim is true.

This is a nice property of such nonlinear superposition operators on $L^p$: as soon as they map from $L^p$ to $L^q$ they are also continuous. See the book by Appell, Zabrejko 'Nonlinear superposition operators'.

For the second: we get $g_n\to g$ in $L^6(L^6)$, which implies convergence in $L^2(L^6)$.

Comment: I think the "hence" in your first statement needs a little clarification: That's exactly the claim OP is asking about, and it's not obvious that just because a (nonlinear) map from $X$ to $Y$ is well-defined it's necessarily continuous.

Comment: He is right. Why do think $f\mapsto f^{1/3}$ is continuous from $L^2$ to $L^6$?

Comment: @Jose27 I expanded the answer. And yes for the special situation of superposition operators, the property that it maps $L^p$  into $L^q$ already implies continuity (if the underlying real function is continuous).